# How can I determine if a Jena Reasoner is a Rule capable reasoner

Tags: java, jena, jena-rules

Jena provides a generic Reasoner interface when returning the reasoner of a model. How can I determine if it is a Rule based, so I can cast it to a `GenericRuleReasoner` and use the methods for manipulating rules?

Note: without using `instanceof` :)

Example

```
// in one part of the app it something like this
OntModelSpec spec = OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM_MICRO_RULE_INF;
OntModel ontologyModel = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(spec, model);

// in another part
Reasoner reasoner = ontologyModel.getReasoner();
```

So now the reasoner is a `com.hp.hpl.jena.reasoner.rulesys.OWLMicroReasoner` determined by `.getClass()` but I want to cast it to a `GenericRuleReasoner` by determining if it IS a rule capable one.

Comment: Why do you not want to use instanceof?

Comment: I'm using it. It just limits me on Jena provided reasoners that extend GenericRuleReasoner. It kind of limits the possibility to plug-in others.